# Deregister all styles and scripts from a certain Wordpress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, codex

i want to wp_deregister all styles and scripts from a certain plugin.

For example

```
$plugin = getAllStyles('PLUGIN-NAME');      
foreach ($plugin as $value) {
    wp_deregister_style($value);
}

$plugin = getAllScripts('PLUGIN-NAME');      
foreach ($plugin as $value) {
    wp_deregister_script($value);
}
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's possible with [MU-PLUGINs](https://premium.wpmudev.org/manuals/wpmu-manual-2/using-mu-plugins/), that looks into request url and selectively disable plugins. That is possible because MU plugins are loaded before regular plugins.

1) Create new Mu-plugin in `/wp-content/mu-plugins/Removeplugin.php`

2) Add this Code

```
/*
    Plugin Name: plugins remover
    Plugin URI: 
    Description:  Removes  plugin
    Author: Author name 
    Version: 1.0
    Author URI: 
*/
```

3) Now add action hook [option_active_plugins](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/disable-a-plugin-to-hook-itself-into-one-precise-blog-page)

```
add_filter( 'option_active_plugins', 'disable_plugin_callback_fun' );
function disable_plugin_callback_fun($plugins){
     $key = array_search( 'plugin_directory_name/plugin_filename.php' , $plugins );
     if ( false !== $key ) unset( $plugins[$key] );
}
```

**Example if you remove the contact form 7 plugin css and js**

```
add_filter( 'option_active_plugins', 'disable_plugin_callback_fun' );
    function disable_plugin_callback_fun($plugins){
        $key = array_search(  'contact-form-7/wp-contact-form-7.php', $plugins );
    if ( false !== $key ) { unset( $plugins[$key] );}

}
```

**NOTE:** This action hook disable the plugin for site,So  i suggest  to Load  plugin from selected page like bellow code Check the current page.

```
$current_page = add_query_arg( array() );
add_filter( 'option_active_plugins', 'disable_plugin_callback_fun' );
        function disable_plugin_callback_fun($plugins){
         $current_page = add_query_arg( array() );   
         if($current_page!='contact'){//contact us page url where to load plugin only 
         $key = array_search(  'contact-form-7/wp-contact-form-7.php', $plugins );
        if ( false !== $key ) { unset( $plugins[$key] );}
        }
    }
```

For more information check this https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/114345/load-plugin-selectively-for-pages-or-posts-etc

> EDIT

If you need remove  only all style and script from plugin. need to find all css and jquery and put it one by one in bellow function.

No other way to remove all the style and script from plugin

**NOTE :** It's only work when plugin used to add style or js useing wp_enqueue_style() and wp_enqueue_script( ) other wise this code is not working

```
add_action('wp_print_scripts', 'disable_pluginsjs_selectively', 100 );
function disable_pluginsjs_selectively( ) {
   wp_deregister_script( Name of the enqueued jQuery);
   wp_dequeue_style('Name of the enqueued stylesheet'); 
}
```

Comment: But code will disable the plugin completely (on special pages). I only want to remove all styles and scripts from the plugin, not the plugin himself.